# Why Cassandra Local Latency P999 is bigger than timeout?

Tags: cassandra

We are using `ColumnFamily.ReadLatency.999percentile` to monitor table's local read latency. But we see the number is huge, sometimes it goes to over 1000 second. But our read timeout set in yaml configuration is only 10s. Is there something wrong with the metrics or read is still working even timeout is reached.

During the huge local latency, I did see the pending read stage is high. So looks like read is hanging after timeout.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: can you provide output of cfhistograms/cfstats?

Comment: cfhistograms returns NaN for read/write latency historgram. But `Max            50.00   9223372036854776000.00   9223372036854776000.00         802187438           7007506`. They are huge, doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Could you add the output of `nodetool cfhistograms`, `nodetool cfstats` to your original question please?

Comment: Or include a link to a github gist or pastebin to it and someone else can

Answer (score 0):

(As of 3.11 at least) There is nothing in the local read that can timeout. Messages are dropped in messaging service as they are received, not in the middle of their processing. So once a local read starts it wont stop until complete. This means that if it takes 90 seconds it will be take that long and be recorded as such, regardless of timeout settings. The client has long since received a timeout or has timed out itself, so when the replica sends this response back it will get dropped then (no one is listening so no reason to look at it).

The reasons for it taking so long are numerous but most likely its from large partitions or too many tombstones (which often causes GC pauses).

Comment: Thanks Chris. We are using 2.1.18. I think it should be the same case that there is no local timeout. And I guess we are having too many range tombstones that causes the huge latency. The worse problem is, some nodes are spent "forever" to handling those queries that there is too many pending read waiting and this causes timeouts and our system load is high because of reading too many tombstones' sstable files...

Comment: Theres options to deal with the tons of tombstones but it depends a lot on use case. Its quite a bit off topic of this question though.